# final argument in 'executeOperation' must be callback error MongoClient.connect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using MongoClient.connect() to open a connection and I'm getting this following error...

```
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:466
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: final argument to `executeOperation` must be a callback
```

however, I'm following the args format stated in the docs...

```
MongoClient.connect(url, options, callback)
```

The exact code I have is :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('there was an error ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('established connection');
  }

  ...some query stuff... 

  db.close();
}
```

MongoDb version: 3.1.6

Any leads on why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Remove `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` and it should work

Comment: @NicolasDelValle, I'm facing same issues. Without that object my code is working but also in console I'm grtting this warning alng with correct output: `(node:14719) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.`